# "HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid" with Salesforce as IdP for implementating SSO

Tags: spring-security, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've implemented SSO using Spring SAML and everything is working fine. It worked with the following IDP's till now:
1) idp.ssocircle.com
2) openidp.feide.no

Now I'm testing with salesforce.com as my Identity Provider. As there is no provision to upload Service Provider Metadata I've done the following configuration settings at its IdP:

Gave my entityID and Assertion Consumer Service URL. I also uploaded my SP certificate. I've downloaded its metadata (idp metadata) which is as follows (hiding the sensitive information):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="https://ABC-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com" validUntil="2024-04-11T13:55:57.307Z">
<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
     <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
           <ds:X509Certificate>XXXXXXXXX</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
     </ds:KeyInfo>
  </md:KeyDescriptor>
  <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://ABC-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost"/>
  <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://ABC-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect"/>
```

Now when I tried to test my SP, first it redirected me to the IDP(salesforce) asking for credentials where I entered them but then after that I was redirected back to my Assertion consumer Service URL(which is my SP) but here an exception was generated saying that

HTTP Status 401 - This request requires HTTP authentication(Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid).

I've tried the following but didn't work :( -
Though not necessary, I've downloaded the certificate file from the salesforce and imported it to my keystore.jks so that to make sure that key is used for signature validation.(Not necessary due to the certificate info already present in IDP metadata).

Here is what I found in my log file(Adding necessary info only after successful AuthnRequest):

```
AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1
.....STARTED_FAILING_HERE.....
Attempting to extract credential from an X509Data
Found 1 X509Certificates
Found 0 X509CRLs
Single certificate was present, treating as end-entity certificate
Credentials successfully extracted from child {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}X509Data by provider org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider
A total of 1 credentials were resolved
Registry could not locate evaluable criteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoCriteria
Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential
Creating XMLSignature object
Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
Signature validated with key from supplied credential
Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key
Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials
Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential
Creating XMLSignature object
Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
Signature did not validate against the credential's key
Signature validation using candidate validation credential failed
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:79)
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine.verifySignature(BaseSignatureTrustEngine.java:142)
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:110)
at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BaseTrustEngineRule.evaluate(BaseTrustEngineRule.java:104)
at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BaseTrustEngineRule.evaluate(BaseTrustEngineRule.java:91)
at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.doEvaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:128)
at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.evaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:107)
at org.opensaml.ws.security.provider.BasicSecurityPolicy.evaluate(BasicSecurityPolicy.java:51)
at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.processSecurityPolicy(BaseMessageDecoder.java:132)
at org.opensaml.ws.message.decoder.BaseMessageDecoder.decode(BaseMessageDecoder.java:83)
at org.opensaml.saml2.binding.decoding.BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.decode(BaseSAML2MessageDecoder.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Failed to verify signature using either KeyInfo-derived or directly trusted credentials
Validation of protocol message signature failed for context issuer 'https://ABC-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com', message type: {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response
Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Incoming SAML message is invalid
Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@153a591
```

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong by looking at the above log. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Abhilash

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your IDP is using a different key for digital signatures than it defines in metadata.

You should inspect the SAML message you received and look for element X509Certificate inside element Signature. Extract the content of the certificate into a separate file, e.g. sales-force-sign.cer

You then need to import the certificate into your samlKeystore.jks, you can find details on how to do it in [chapter 4.5 (Key management)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) of the Spring SAML manual. Make sure to note the alias you import the key with.

As last step you need to tell Spring SAML to use the newly imported key for signature verifications for your IDP, for that you should update your securityContext.xml and update your ExtendedMetadta for your IDP with property signingKey and value of the alias you used earlier to import the key. It will look similar to:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
              <constructor-arg>
                  <value type="java.io.File">classpath:salesforce_metadata.xml</value>
              </constructor-arg>
              <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
          </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
              <property name="signingKey" value="sf-proxy"/>
          </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

Again you can find details on all of this in the manual.

Alternatively you can simply add the key you extracted from the message into your IDP metadata. Just manualy update the XML file and add another KeyDescriptor with use="signing". It might be faster to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked finally. You are just too awesome! :D

Comment: My pleasure, you can of course upvote the answers ;)

Comment: Yeah I would've done that..but I don't have enough reputation(15) to do so :(

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, it saved  me :)